How to maintain auxillary calculations on separate sheet in Excel?
In Excel, I'm trying to maintain some auxiliary calculations on a separate sheet.
But each time I add a row or column in the main sheet, Excel keeps updating the formulas on the "side-sheet". So the rows/columns there do not match up with the "main-sheet" anymore.
Similar to this setup:
Main sheet:



Side sheet:



Note that the calculations on the side-sheet extend beyond the rows/columns of the main sheet. This is meant to account for any new rows/columns to be added.
When I insert new rows in the main sheet, Excel automatically updates the formulas in the side-sheet. So, there are no auxiliary calculations for new row I just added.
I know I can make fixed references using $ to prevent Excel from updating the respective entries.
But the sheets are rather large (>100 rows/columns), so I would like to write the formula once and then copy/paste to all cells.
During c/p, I need Excel to update the row/column references to create the side-sheet in the first place. Afterwards, I would like to prevent Excel from updating the formulas. Any way of achieving this goal?

Try using absolute references in your formulas. Ex.: =Main!$B$1*2

If I understand correctly, You might be able to convert your data in the main tab to a table, then formulas in the side tab could reference the table itself. This would allow the side tab to dynamically change based on changes to the main tab.

In B1 you can enter:
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),,,"Main"))*2

This formula can be copied and does not change when you insert or delete rows/columns in the Main sheet.
But it may be relatively slow (INDIRECT is a volatile function).
Another posibility:
=INDEX(Main!$A$1:$Z$100,ROW(),COLUMN())*2

In this case, you should predict what formula range you will need.

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=volatile+function

Do you just want your side sheet to be a read-only copy of the main sheet? If so, you can just reference a range as an array. Even better, if you format your original data as a table, you can just reference the table itself, either as the whole table or as individual columns. Then if you need to do additional calculations, I find it easiest to just reference the original table columns or rows and use array calculations with Spilling (Excel 2021 and later) so that inserting cells in the original table is just automatically updated.
One downside is the original table formatting doesn't come through (and you can't use array formulas that spill inside structured tables):

But if you are okay with having to reformat it, you can use it relatively conveniently. If you reference an entire column from your main sheet's table, for example, you can do auxiliary calculations on your side sheet then chain other columns from that calculation be reference it using Spill Range References:

You can also use the FILTER function to pull in columns or rows from your first sheet and limit their array sizes to non-blank cells, or use the INDEX function to create a dynamic named range that resizes based on your data (just learned about this myself). In short, using array form has several powerful features and I use it a lot. More info and comments:

